# when a base class pointer point to a base class object whether the compiler will use dynamic binding?

Tags: c++

I know that when use a base class pointer which point to a derived class object to call a virtual function, the compiler will use dynamic binding to call the derived version.
But when use a base class pointer which point to a base class object to call a virtual function, does the compiler use dynamic binding or static binding to call the virtual 
function?

For example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void show()
    {
        cout << "base class";
    }
}
int main()
{
    Base *pb; //Base class pointer
    Base b;   //Base class object
    pb = &b;
    pb->show(); //Is static binding or dynamic binding?
}
```

Because My English is very bad, so I want to make my question as simple as possible, but I will describle my question in more detail in follow:

Actually the problem stems from that I am summarizing how to trigger dynamic binding.
At first I summary the trigger condition are:

1. the function must a virtual function.
2. must use pointer or reference to call the function.

The two trigger condition cause the problem that I asked:
"when a base class pointer point to a base class object whether the compiler will use dynamic binding?"

I have google for search answer, and I find a fragment (the demo is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cellcomp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.cell.doc/language_ref/cplr139.html)):

```
struct A {
   virtual void f() { cout << "Class A" << endl; }
};

struct B: A {
   //Note that it not overrides A::f.
   void f(int) { cout << "Class B" << endl; }
};

struct C: B {
   void f() { cout << "Class C" << endl; }
};

int main() {
   B b; C c;
   A* pa1 = &b;
   A* pa2 = &c;
//   b.f();
   pa1->f(); 
   pa2->f();
}
```

The following is the output of the above example:

```
"Class A"
"Class C"
```

According to `pa1->f()` will output `Class A`, I summary third trigger condition:

3.function in base class must be overridden in the derived class.

Now according to the three trigger condition, when use a base class pointer which point to a base class object to call a virtual function, the compiler will use static binding to call the virtual function, because the virtual is not overridden.

But when use a derived class pointer which point to a derived class object to call a virtual function, it will use dynamic binding, because the virtual is overridden.

It made me very confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can choose whichever, or neither, depending on how smart it is and how well it can detect. The rule is **polymorphism must work**. How this is achieved is an implementation detail.

If the same end-result can be achieved with both dynamic or static binding, as is the case here, both are valid options for the compiler.

In your case, the function doesn't have to be called at all - the generated code could be just as well identical to code generated by

```
int main()
{
    cout << "base class";
}
```

Comment: The rule is _the binding must be dynamic_.  Everything you say after this basically correct, however; the compiler can use any technique it wants, provided the correct function is called.

Comment: @JamesKanze all I can find is "Virtual functions support dynamic binding and object-oriented programming. A class that declares or
inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class."

Comment: Exactly. "Virtual functions support dynamic binding."  In other words, if you call a virtual function, dynamic binding is in effect.  (Or in other words, if the standard uses the words, then they don't refer to how something is implemented, but rather to the observable effect that the compiler is required to achieve.)

Comment: @JamesKanze oh, I interpret "support" as in "can have"

Comment: In this case, "support" and "can have" aren't much different.  The standard speaks in terms of "observable behavior", and I think you'd agree that there's nothing optional or implementation defined in the require observable behavior.  (But I'm nit picking on vocabulary.  Globally, your response is very well written, and I'm sure it's clear to everyone, even if one can argue for subtle differences in the choice of words.)

Comment: Hi, @JamesKanze and Luchian Grigore I think "support" means that "virtual function" is one of trigger condition of dynamic binding.And I want to know all the trigger condition of dynamic binding.In other words,I want to know all the trigger condition that if I satisfy these condition, the dynamic binding **MUST** happen.

Comment: @jumpcoder The standard is clear.  If after name lookup and function overload resolution, the chosen function is virtual (either because it was declared virtual, or because it overrides a virtual function in a base class), the function dynamically bound; i.e. the function in the most derived class of the actual runtime object is called.  How the compiler does this is its problem, and will vary from one compiler to the next.  (As Luchian points out, the function may even be inlined, or not called at all.)

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on compiler optimization. Compiler might be clever enough to figure out that `Base::show` is always the one called or it might not. You can look at the disassembly to find out. You can force static-binding with `b->Base::show()`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No. At least in theory not. Because in theory, the compiler does not know wether the pointer points to a `Base`, a `Derived` or to `YetAnotherDerived` object. Therefore it has to apply the same mechanism regardless of the dynamic type of the object.

**But:** In practise, compilers have optimizers, capable of identifying some use cases where the dynamic type is known. I your case it can detect the aliasing, meaning it knows that `pb` points to `b` and that it is a local variable and cannot be changed concurrently, so it knows that in fact you are calling `b.show()` and will abbreviate the output to reflect that fact and get rid of the virtual dispatch. Similar optimizations are possible e.g. in this code:

```
auto pb = make_unique<Base>();
pb->show();
```

But as any optimization it is up to the compiler if it applies them - the standard says virtual dispatch happens even if the pointer points to a Base object, and that's it.

Comment: +1: the Standard says it's a dynamic binding, but the Standard is only concerned about semantics.